# Ignore certain characters from a character set in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code which replaces control characters:

```
String str = "Apple\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "> --"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Mango\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Kiwi\n"
                + "Papaya\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Orange\n";

str = str.replaceAll("(?m)((^[\\p{C}]*)|([\\p{C}]*$))", "");
```

I want to remove all control characters except the new line (\n) from the start of the line and the end of the line. The problem I am having in that `\n` is a part of `\\p{C}` set. How do I modify this regex to ensure it replaces all characters except the `\n` character.

Comment: Using Java `[\p{C}&&[^\n]]`

Comment: @anubhava OP only wanted to keep ``\n``, not ``\r``, and why did you double ``\`` on one ``\\n`` but not the other? Consistency is good when coding.